# WinMo 6.5 sync error: The following appointments failed to synchronize from the device

Tags: sync, windows-mobile, mobile-phone, activesync

I can't sync my phone with my PC, this is the error:

```
The following appointments failed to synchronize from the device...
```

I looked for this appointment but I can't find it.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard reset did the job.